# OrientDB SQL gives different results for complex query with OR filters and for cascade of simple queries

Tags: orientdb

I started using OrientDB and stuck with some weird behavior on complex queries.

I'd like to get a graph neighborhood of several nodes. I'm interested in the nodes containing "AD" substring in `string` attribute, nodes containing attribute `ontology_id` with value `D017628` and nodes that are related to them with depth up to 3.

Could anyone explain why I have different results for complex query with "OR":

`TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT * FROM V WHERE ontology_id="D017628" or string LIKE "%AD%") WHILE $depth<=3`

And I can get more results if I decompose the query above into 2 separate queries and run them separately:

`TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT * FROM V WHERE ontology_id="D017628") WHILE $depth<=3
TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT * FROM V WHERE string LIKE "%AD%") WHILE $depth<=3`

Why does it happen? Isn't it correct to join different criteria with OR statement within `SELECT`?

Comment: By different results do you mean a different order in which they are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the TRAVERSE statement, you have to take into consideration two details:

- by default the traversal is made depth-first
- traversed nodes are never re-traversed.

Now consider a graph made of four vertices:

```
A, B, C, D
```

connected as follows:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
A -> C
```

(a triangle made of A, B, C, plus an edge from C to D)

Now, suppose you do the TRAVERSE starting from A, with $depth <= 2

You can have this traversal

```
A (depth = 0)
A -> B (depth = 1)
B -> C (depth = 2)
C -> D (depth = 3, so D is discarded)
A -> C (you encounter C, that was already traversed, so this path is discarded)
```

The result of this traversal is `A, B, C` of course.

Now consider that (by pure luck) the traversal starts from the other path:

```
A (depth = 0)
A -> C (depth = 1)
C -> D (depth = 2)
A -> B (depth = 1)
B -> C (you encounter C, that was already traversed, so this path is discarded)
```

The result in this case is `A, C, D, B`

As you can see, you have two different results based on how the graph is traversed.

A possible solution here is to try to force the traversal to use a breadth-first strategy:

```
TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT * FROM V WHERE ontology_id="D017628" or string LIKE "%AD%") WHILE $depth<=3 STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST
```

This will help, but probably it won't completely solve the problem.

Another possible solution is to write a single query with a unionAll():

```
SELECT unionAll($a, $b)
LET
$a = (TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT * FROM V WHERE ontology_id="D017628") WHILE $depth<=3),
$b = (TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT * FROM V WHERE string LIKE "%AD%") WHILE $depth<=3)
```

If you are doing an actual graph traversal (so you can replace `TRAVERSE *` with `TRAVERSE both()`), you can rewrite the query with a MATCH statement (the MATCH does not discard duplicates):

```
MATCH
   {class:V, as:a, where:(ontology_id="D017628" or string LIKE "%AD%")} -E- {as:b, while:($depth < 3)}
RETURN $elements
```